# Remove border in each table cell in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios9, tablecell

I would like to remove border bottom line of each Question table rows. Another thing is that I would like to remove the left padding space in each row. 
How to implement it in swift iOS 9.0 .

[image]

Comment: I think You should use Custom Cell Having two labels for Question & Answer..!!!

Answer (score 24):

You can remove bottom border by writing this below line in viewdidLoad,

```
self.tblMyTable.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
```

And Remove left padding by writing this in cellForRow,

```
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
```

Update for Swift 3.0:

```
cell?.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
cell?.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
```

Comment: Your code is remove border totally. I just want to remove the border bottom line of "Question" rows. So, if I remove this "Question" and "Answer" looks like in one row/one group. I want like this.

Comment: It would be better if you display question and answer both in single cell by using Custom cell. Is it possible for you?

Comment: It would be great. How could I make it? I'm new for iOS . I'm just learning by viewing tutorials. Currently, I got the data from Rest. .Please help me.

Comment: You have to give question and answer both in custom cell (two different label or else). I think it will be easy for you.

Answer (score 12):

select tableview in storyboard and select seperator style to None[image]

Comment: god I was looking for an "imaginary" bottom extra space... thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Another simple solution that worked for me for removing bottom lines (separators) just for empty rows - tested on **Swift 4, Xcode 9 & iOS 11**:

```
class viewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView?.tableFooterView = UIView()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the method below

```
class viewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, UIScreen.main.bounds.width, 0, 0)

        }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks